# filter by data and calculate average vuejs

Tags: vue.js, average, pinia

I have a table in firebase named products and one of its params is product, productivity and etc.,

Now I want to filter this table by product (they can contain many different products) and retrieve an average of productivity.

This is how far I can get without any errors I know that somewhere I have to filter data and pass argument but couldn't get an answer. I am using Pinia and VUEJS 3 and trying to get result with getters

```
getters: {
getAve:(state) => {
      let sum = 0
      state.orders.forEach(  (order)  =>  sum += (order.productivity)  )
      return sum / state.orders.length      
    },
}
```

later on I am using v-for where in template I would pass `{{ getAve(order.product)}}`

p.s. I am new to vuejs and codding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I was looking for, maybe someone else will need. I use this method in my componenet:

```
const averageProd = (id) => {
  let average = [];
for (var i = 0; i < storeOrders.orders.length; i++) {
    if (storeOrders.orders[i].product === id) {
        average.push(storeOrders.orders[i]);
    }}
    return average.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.productivity, 0) / average.length
    
}
```